# Add event handler (MouseDown) dynamically for PathFigure C# WPF

Tags: wpf, canvas, polyline, pathgeometry, figures

I created an object from points with this code, dynamically:

```
SolidColorBrush brushColor = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(_brushColor);

PathFigure figures = new PathFigure();
figures.StartPoint = points[0];
points.RemoveAt(0);
figures.Segments = new PathSegmentCollection(points.Select((p, i) => new LineSegment(p, i % 2 == 0)));
PathGeometry pg = new PathGeometry();
pg.Figures.Add(figures);
canvas.Children.Add(new Path { Stroke = brushColor, StrokeThickness = 3, Data = pg });
```

Now I want to add event handler for this object. Would not be a problem if object is a path or polyline type. I would just add event handler like this:

```
poly.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(poly_MouseDown);

void poly_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     //code
}
```

Problem is that I have to use Figures and PathGeometry which does not accept MouseDown event handlers. Since they are from System.Windows.**Media** class and Path/Polyline is from System.Windows.**Shapes** I can't find a solution to assign right event handler (MouseDown) to my Figure object.

What is the solution or is there any nice workaround solution for this problem? Maybe cast or convert it somehow?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302791/polylines-extended-on-canvas-while-overdrawing-with-use-of-pointcollection-c-sha/40303995#40303995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you're skipping a crucial step.
Declare the `Path` Object first, give it the event, and then insert it into your `Canvas`:

```
SolidColorBrush brushColor = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter ().ConvertFromString (_brushColor);

PathFigure figures = new PathFigure ();
figures.StartPoint = points[0];
points.RemoveAt (0);
figures.Segments = new PathSegmentCollection (points.Select ((p, i) => new LineSegment (p, i % 2 == 0)));
PathGeometry pg = new PathGeometry ();
pg.Figures.Add (figures);
Path pgObject = new Path({ Stroke = brushColor, StrokeThickness = 3, Data = pg });
pgObject.MouseDown+=new MouseButtonEventHandler(poly_MouseDown);
canvas.Children.Add (pgObject);
```